# Não consigo passar corretamente os argumentos para a função que atualiza dados no banco (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, crud

Estou usando Laravel 5.6 e me deparei com um problema na hora que tento editar registros do banco de dados:

Passo da tabela que mostra os dados e opções (editar, excluir, etc), para a página de edição, e quando finalizo e passo para a função atualizar (abaixo), um erro é retornado:

> Too few arguments to function
>   App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::atualizar(), 0 passed and
>   exactly 2 expected

Função

```
public function atualizar($id, $corpo){
        $conteudo = Conteudo::find($id);
        $conteudo->corpo = $corpo;
        $conteudo->save();
        //return redirect()->route('');
    }
```

Página editar.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{action('PagesController@atualizar', $id)}}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}     
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $conteudo['id'] }}"/>
                        <textarea class="12u$" name="corpo" id="corpo">{{$conteudo['corpo']}}</textarea>
                    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button small submit">Salvar
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você envia o formulário, os dados vem com a classe Request.

O ideal seria você adicionar como segundo parâmetro uma request, ja com injeção de dependência:

```
public function atualizar($id, Request $request){
    $conteudo = Conteudo::findOrFail($id);
    $corpo = $request->get('corpo');
    $conteudo->corpo = $corpo;
    $conteudo->save();
}
```

Desta forma, você consegue pegar qualquer dado que venha adicionar no formulário.

[Referência](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Porém ainda encontro o mesmo problema:
"Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::atualizar(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected"

Comment: No action do form, você pode usar o helper route() do Laravel.
Para isso, vá no seu arquivo de rotas, ache a rota em questão e chame o método adicional:

`->route('nome.da.sua.rota');`.

No form, faça isso:

`<form ... action="{{ route('nome.da.sua.rota', ['id' => $seu_id]) }}>`

Referência: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#named-routes

Comment: No momento em que acesso as variáveis através de `$_POST['x']`, o código funciona.
Função atualizar:
       `$conteudo = Conteudo::find($_POST['id']);
        $conteudo->corpo = $_POST['corpo'];
        $conteudo->save();`

Comment: O seguinte erro é retornado quando uso `->route('atualizar'); ` no web.php:
"**Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::route does not exist.**"

Comment: Comenta a rota inteira aqui.

Comment: `Route::get('inicio', 'PagesController@inicio')->name('inicio');
Route::get('mostrar', 'PagesController@mostrar'); 
Route::get('editar/{id}', 'PagesController@editar')->name('editar');
Route::post('atualizar', 'PagesController@atualizar')->route('atualizar');`

Comment: A rota atualizar tem que ser do tipo `PUT`, e faltou você colocar o parâmetro {id} ta rota atualizar também.

PS: Com o Laravel nunca use $_GET['any'], pois o trabalho de rotas para a controller, faz toda uma tratativa de segurança com os dados.